# How can I obtain the inverse transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

> The inverse Fourier transform is defined as:
>
> $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[g](x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(k) e^{i k x} d k$$

I can't get an inverse Fourier Transform to

> Q1: $$g(k)=\cos (\sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 })$$
> Q2:
> $$g(k)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 }}\sin (\sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 })$$

I don't know if it's possible .

Comment: Are you sure their inverse transforms really do have a closed form?

Comment: No , I am not sure .